Algorithm for determining program is installed on the system
I have this program that claims to determine if DOSBOX is installed on the system regardless of the location of the executable folder
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Search DOSBox

REM Búsqueda en registro de 32 bits
set "FOUND=0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic product where "name like '%%DOSBox%%'" get name /value 2^>nul') do (
    echo DOSBox encontrado: %%a
    set "FOUND=1"
)

REM Búsqueda en registro de 64 bits
if %FOUND%==0 (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic product where "name like '%%DOSBox%%'" get name /value 2^>nul') do (
        echo DOSBox encontrado: %%a
        set "FOUND=1"
    )
)

REM Búsqueda adicional por nombre parcial
if %FOUND%==0 (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic product where "name like '%%DOS%%'" get name /value 2^>nul') do (
        echo Posible DOSBox encontrado: %%a
        set "FOUND=1"
    )
)

if %FOUND%==0 (
    echo DOSBox NO está instalado en el sistema.
) else (
    echo DOSBox está INSTALADO en el sistema.
)

pause

The problem is that it always says it is not installed when it is. How can I fix the algorithm so that it always gives the correct answer?

It relies on wmic, so what is the query result when you run it in your system? Alternatively use other approach aside from wmic

WMIC.exe  a relatively slow command utility to run for the first time in a session. In addition, using Win32_Product is a very bad idea, which should be avoided. It only returns applications installed via Windows Installer. There are many products used to assemble installers that don’t build Windows Installer packages. Any applications that use these non-Windows Installer packages for deployment won’t be returned. Additionally running it actually performs a consistency check on all Windows Installer applications and this performs automatic and silent repairs on any of those which failed.

Worked fine for me. I'd suggest that you check that your editor is saving in ANSI. Don't use a word-processor as they have a habit of reformatting the text in an attempt to make it seem more like natural language. I use Editplus but there are others that a good Googling will find like Notepad++. Notepad is barely adequate as it tries to word-process code. Using Boolean - set found to %%a - you can then test found for whatever DOS you need by matching against %%DOS%%. which would save you iterations

It was ny understanding that DOSBox does not need to be installed, (it can essentially just be extracted from the installer package). As such it may never appear in the programs list or in fact register consistent information to the usual registry branches. For that reason, the only way to determine if an end user has it already, is to perform an extensive and recursive search of every subirectory on every available drive on their system. I would strongly advise agaist that. The only sensible option is to ask the end user to navigate to their own known location, if installed, or download it!

Could you use the where command  - eg where dosbox.exe

@cup, the where utility, presumed to be %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe, will search the current working directory and all locations listed in the User and System environments under the Path name for files named dosbox.exe. This presumes therefore that the location has been specifically added to one of those variable values. I'd say, especially in the case of an end user simply extracting the files from the installer, that this would be a non robust and unlikely scenario. In addition, there is no requirement for anyone to ever add locations to Path, or for installers to force it.
